# SelectedCells.Count and SelectedCells[0].RowIndex

Tags: wpf, grid, selection

In WinForms it is such a thing like:

```
if (dataGridViewControll.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
    EditorForm.ID = dataGridViewControll.Rows[dataGridViewControll.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Does anyone knows how to do such tricks in a WPF `Grid`?  I mean `SelectedCells` and `SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value`.

Comment: The formatting of your question needs fixing.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question please?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: WPF is *wildly* different from WinForms. Trying to carry over techniques and tricks is futile.

Comment: I try to get a Index of selected row in DevExpress WPF grid.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that is possible, but the property names and techniques vary and depend on which grid you decide to use. Infragistics does it, as far as i remember it. Was that your question?

However, please bear in mind that the WPF *Grid* is **not a data grid** but mere a control for structuring your layout. Therefore i assume you refer to some other grid control?

edit: Wait, that question is years old, why did it pop up under news?